# Change Font on Wordpress Site

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

Very new to web development. I have 3rd party theme on my website. I am trying to change the font in the theme. I can't find a FONT section in the customize section of the website because of the theme I am using. I want to change the font on the website to Garamond.
Please, can anyone suggest me in the right direction? 
Website is www.croiativefilms.ie

Comment: Is there anything in your styles.css relating to `font-family`? If you used a 3rd-party theme then it's probably best asking the themes author - as they could have placed it anywhere.

Comment: which font you want to use?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should have to be open your particular theme dashboard in that go to the appearance in that your theme is there like your theme name go to in that theme options. next in theme options click on styling. In styling there is a typography option is there you have to click on that option you can see the fonts there is the body, headings like h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, menu, slider etc fonts are there you can set the fonts as you like in your particular WordPress theme.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the font in the customize section is only possible if the theme has activated this specific functionality.

WordPress has an integrated custom CSS feature in this section. The following will change the font-family of the body to Garamond if it is installed on the users computer, otherwise it will fall back to another serif font (usually Times):

```
body {
   font-family: Garamond, serif;
}
```

There are some [web save](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) fonts wich are installed almost everywhere. If it is really important that is is Garamond, create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) from the theme you are using and embed the font there so the browser will download it if it isn't installed yet.

Answer (score -1):

check this options as per my screenshot.

http://spyropress.com/docs/monaco/

[image]